# Use the full Fourier Transform in x to solve

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis

Use the full Fourier Transform in x to solve:

$$ u_{xx} + u_{yy} =0 \, \,\,\, -\infty<x<\infty\,,\,\, 0<y<1$$
$$u(x,0) = \left\{
  \begin{array}{l l}
    0 & \quad \text{if $x<0$}\\
    e^{-x} & \quad \text{if $0\leq x$}
  \end{array} \right.$$

$$u(x,1)=0\,,\,\,\,-\infty < x < \infty$$

Comment: Do you know what happens when you take the Fourier transform of a derivative of a function?

Comment: Frank: I offer a solution to the problem you posed above.  Please let me know if it is useful.

Answer (score 1):

Begin by writing the FT of $u$ as

$$\hat{u}(k,y) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx \: u(x,y) \, e^{i k x}$$

Then the PDE can be rewritten as

$$\frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2} \hat{u}(k,y) = k^2 \hat{u}(k,y)$$

The general solution to this equation is

$$\hat{u}(k,y) = A e^{k y} + B e^{-k y}$$

Now use the boundary conditions to find $A$ and $B$.

$$\hat{u}(k,0) = A+B =\int_{0}^{\infty} dx \: e^{-x} \, e^{i k x} = \frac{1}{1-i k}$$

$$\hat{u}(k,1) = A e^k + B e^{-k} = 0$$

I leave it to the reader to do the algebra.  The end result is that we may write the solution $u(x,y)$ by taking the inverse FT of $\hat{u}(k,y)$:

$$u(x,y) = \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dk \: \hat{u}(k,y) \, e^{-i k x}$$

or,

$$\begin{align}u(x,y) &= \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{dk}{1-i k} \frac{\sinh{[(1-y) k]}}{\sinh{k}} e^{-i k x}\\ &= \frac{1}{4 \pi} \int_{0}^{\infty} dx' \: \frac{\sin{\pi y}}{\cosh{\pi (x-x')} - \cos{\pi y}} e^{-x'} \end{align}$$

For the latter integral, I used the [convolution theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ConvolutionTheorem.html).  It is unclear whether this integral has a closed form.